# Why does MQTT Mosquito attempt ot remove a package?

Tags: apt, package-management, mqtt

Context: OSMC distro on Raspberry Pi Zero-W. MQTT Mosquitto package installation failed.

Why would an attempt to:

`sudo apt-get install mosquitto`

trigger an attempt to remove an OSMC package?

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ssh-app-osmc
```

Log:

```
osmc@osmczero:~$ sudo apt-get install mosquitto 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libev4 libuv1 libwebsockets8
Suggested packages:
  apparmor
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ssh-app-osmc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libev4 libuv1 libwebsockets8 mosquitto
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/314 kB of archives.
After this operation, 673 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 34694 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ssh-app-osmc (1.2.3) ...
Removing 'diversion of /etc/ssh/sshd_config to /etc/ssh/sshd_config.distributed by ssh-app-osmc'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/etc/ssh/sshd_config' with
  different file '/etc/ssh/sshd_config.distributed', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package ssh-app-osmc (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssh-app-osmc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## UPDATE

Dependency query:

```
osmc@osmczero:~$ apt-cache show ssh-app-osmc
Package: ssh-app-osmc
Origin: OSMC
Version: 1.2.3
Essential: No
Pre-Depends: openssh-server
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Sam G Nazarko <email@samnazarko.co.uk>
Priority: required
Section: metapackages
Filename: pool/main/s/ssh-app-osmc/ssh-app-osmc_1.2.3_all.deb
Size: 3168
SHA256: 6fe60f2956b2d5105d9da82693f1747195be55ce81a6e4b4085ab5acc0af33fb
SHA1: edcb33f8a2f0ed82028e31e53ae6889dc99714f5
MD5sum: 9602092e26c9fe46596dc2165759b78d
Description: SSH server for OSMC with prepopulated configuration
Description-md5: a4e3a71ca28452ae99a476d87b31377c
Installed-Size: 38
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the ssh-app-osmc package?

Comment: my guess is that `ssh-app-osmc` depends on a particular version of either `libev4`, `libuv1`, `libwebsockets8`, and/or `mosquitto` and upgrading it or them to an incompatible version is what triggers the removal.   You can check the Depends: line (e.g. with `apt-cache show ssh-app-osmc | grep '^Depends:'`) to see what it depends on.

Comment: You'll probably have to delay upgrading mosquitto until there's a new release of the ssh-app-osmc package which depends on the new, updated lib or mosquitto packages.

Comment: @cas Thanks: please see OP under the section `Updates`

Comment: that's odd, there's no direct Depends: conflict.   And neither mosquitto nor the lib packages have any relevant Conflicts: lines (at least, the versions on my debian sid box don't...probably the same on your rpi).   Maybe try `aptitude why-not ssh-app-osmc`

Comment: @cas  `aptitude` does not install for the same reason as described in the original posting

Comment: does `apt-get -d -f install` show anything interesting?  (note: the `-d` is important - it tells apt-get to download only...and indirectly stops apt-get from actually installing or removing any packages).

Comment: @cas Yes,  despite issuing the `-d` option it indicates it will attempt to remove the package `ssh-app-osmc`

Comment: did it want to install or remove anything else?  can you post the full output of that `apt-get -d -f install` command?    BTW, what is OSMC?  is it some kind of debian-based rpi distro?  or is it just some third-party repository to add packages to raspbian or something?